# Css to display divs in row and cols

Tags: html, css

I have an array of data and need to create divs in sequence. The problem is to display these divs like below:

[image]

Is it possible to do it in CSS?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched the internet for "HTML table layout" or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Used a `flexbox` to achieve the above configuration.

Please check and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 150px;
}
.wrapper > div {
  background: #ddd;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```